# Trigger validation based on save button acumatica

Tags: customization, acumatica

I'm considering using action save on a form , say customer file , to enable a pop up warning message. For example if the user hasn't filled in a certain attribute field depending on the customer class a warning message box will provide an alert. Using save button as the trigger .. Is it a good option, will there be any potential issues if acumatica change the code around save button defaults?
Thanks

Comment: Q: have you completed the Acumatica developer training courses? (T100/T200/T300)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Gabriel mentioned you should review the developer training to get the best answer. Even more so on how to use AEF to write the customization correctly to override a graph such as customer maintenance. I would use RowPersisting to validate during a save. The training material should assist in the best way to do this because you need to extend the current Customer_RowPersisting call with your additional checks. Look at the source for "Customer_RowPersisting" or just "_RowPersisting" for examples. I think T300 is the course that will help you with the PXOverrideAttribute

Comment: thanks for helpful comments, currently I'm going through the course so no I haven't completed. Question came about because one of my colleagues who has completed the course refuse to overwrite the save button logic.  Anyway once I complete the course I will know better